# How to find offset/index base on id with order?

Tags: postgresql

How to find offset/index base on id with order?

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM product p
WHERE p.id = $1
ORDER BY p.id desc NULLS LAST
```

id:1 return 0

```
id |
1  |
2  |
3  |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *the number of rows with a smaller `id` value*:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM product WHERE id < $1;
```

Comment: thanks for reply, the query with order by .. , so if I use count seems there will be error ..

Comment: @user1775888: Not sure what you are asking. If you clarify your question, I might have an answer.

Comment: I use this in my pagination function,I try to find offset to use in select offset, limit query  get next rows list, I have last request rows list max_id . and the query have order by. the order by column datatype is string not integer so I can't just use `< >`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099

Comment: That seems still use integer column be the key order .. if column datatype is string can't use < >. currently my solution is select all order by ...(string column)  and loop the output rows list find if id = last_max_id .. offset = list[i] + 1, this works but I'm worry about the performance, is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: OFFSET is inefficient. Why use it when you already have the `id` you need? You can still use `WHERE id > last_max_id`, doesn't matter if it's a text or integer column.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  I know offset is inefficient, thats why I ask the question. `You can still use WHERE id > last_max_id, doesn't matter if it's a text or integer column` -  If order by string_column desc/asc thats means id is not desc/asc,  the where id > last_max_id  , how could get the correct rows??

Comment: I meant you can use the string_column (or whatever is used for the ORDER BY), for that: `WHERE string_column > max_string_column`. Read the above linked answer by Erwin.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ is that work? I thought < > only for integer

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the link Erwin provide the column index is integer , I can't find postgresql doc, does <> operator works with string??

Comment: You can try it ;)